# (typescript) facing problem trying to pass font-awsome icon as object to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, font-awesome

Error: Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'IconProp'.
Type 'object' is not assignable to type '[IconPrefix, IconName]'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(25, 3): The expected type comes from property 'icon' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FontAwesomeIconProps'

```
interface Props {
  img: object;
}
```

Parent Component:

```
import { faBriefcaseMedical } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
<MissionCards img={faBriefcaseMedical} />
```

Child Component:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={Props.img} />
```

Comment: can you provide the type for `Props.img`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can import that type like so

```
import { IconProp } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
interface Props {
   img: IconProp;
}
```

[source](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/issues/366)

Answer (score 10):

You can simply sort it out as follows:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { IconProp } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch as IconProp} />
```